# Android App (Kivy or Ai) freezes when I try to connect BLE on Arduino Uno

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, arduino, kivy

Sorry for my English. This forum solved many times my problems just by reading some other questions.

I have a Grove BLE v1 on Base Shield v2 on an Arduino Uno. I am trying to send bytes over BT with my Galaxy Note (Android 4.4). Pairing is OK.

Some apps work correctly like BLE Scanner or HMBLEComAssistant. (Can connect and send some bytes). But, using an app created with App Inventor, or using an app created with Python Kivy like [Link](https://gist.github.com/tito/7432757), my App freezes every times I try to connect to BT. The led of my BLE turns on continuously like it was connected. 
In all my apps, I can see and get names or MAC addresses of paired devices.

Does someone get the same problem? Is my 4.4 Android having trouble with BLE?

Is there a problem with `BTsocket.connect()` like I read in this question?
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530100)

Thanks for reading this question and for this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, its seems to be that BLE is not as a classic BT. Have to use connectGatt().

I can now connect whith my BLE whitout freezing in my Kivy App but can't send any data for now.

Will search for this.

Comment: My Grove_BLE don't use EDR mode (no dual-mode). It was the problem. Now it works in BLE mode. If someone wants to see a kind of solution : [link](http://tableauxmaths.fr/spip/spip.php?article156)