# Android Bluetooth Socket connect() method blocks forever without errors

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect my Android app with a Bluetooth (classic) peripheral.

After finding the device through a scan, I create a BluetoothSocket without problems. However, mySocket.connect() blocks forever.

```
public void run(BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter) {
    // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    try {
        // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
        mySocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
        try {
            mySocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Why a connection timeout error is not thrown?

PS: both my app and the peripheral make use of the default UUID ("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"), so this should not be my problem.

Comment: Hope helps [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530100/bluetooth-on-android-my-socket-connect-blocks-forever-and-socket-close-does)

Comment: Unfortunately, I read that post and nothing helped me

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I tried many things but nothing helps.

Comment: Are you implementing both client/server modules for the same device?